# Trying to take count results and give them their own column

Tags: oracle

I am making my first post here since I have not been able to find a solution on my own. I have little programming/sql/oracle knowledge, but I occasionally work with (I believe) Oracle databases.

What I am trying to accomplish is taking a query result and giving each COUNT() its own column. the reason for this is to make a report for a web application. I need the results to fill a column of their own in order to parse out fields for the report designer.

My query looks like the following:

`SELECT ISSUE, 
COUNT(ISSUE) AS ISSUE_COUNT
FROM ISSUE_TABLE
WHERE TIME >TO_DATE('08/10/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND TIME <TO_DATE('08/11/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY ISSUE`

This would return a result as follows:

```
ISSUE      | ISSUE_COUNT
------------------------
A          | 30
B          | 4
C          | 24
D          | 17
```

What I'd like to end up with is something like this:

```
ISSUE        | A  | B  | C  | D  |
----------------------------------
ISSUE_COUNT  | 30 | 4  | 24 | 17 |
```

I need to ensure that each ISSUE_COUNT is unique in its own column or the report application will not parse out the results to display when reports are run. I thought about using PIVOT, but have not found any solution that uses COUNT() or SUM().

Comment: What you need is the `PIVOT` clause. Here's a quick link: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: For each of the resulting "ISSUES" (like A, B, C, etc.), you can use something like: `SUM(DECODE(ISSUE, 'A', ISSUE_COUNT, 0)) AS "A"`. I would do smth like `SELECT 'ISSUE_COUNT AS ISSUE, SUM(DECODE(ISSUE, 'A', ISSUE_COUNT, 0)) AS "A" from ... `. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unless you have a fixed list of issues you'd have to do that dynamically; it's probably something the reporting layer should be doing based on the results of your current query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `PIVOT` clause. Try this query:

`SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT ISSUE,
    COUNT(ISSUE) AS ISSUE_COUNT
  FROM ISSUE_TABLE
  WHERE TIME >TO_DATE('08/10/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND TIME   <TO_DATE('08/11/2017 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  GROUP BY ISSUE
  )PIVOT (SUM(ISSUE_COUNT) FOR ISSUE IN ('A','B','C','D'))`

Comment: This answer worked. However, it did give me an "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error. Adding one more parenthesis at the end fixed it. :)

Comment: Is there something I can add to make any of the fields that return NULL into a zero?

Comment: @katfysh You can use the `NVL` function. `NVL(value_to_be_evalueated, value_to_return)`